# firebase auth - duplicate class: io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

Tags: flutter, dart, build

Build fails with error: duplicate class: io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

Build was successful when run 1 hr ago

Have tried cleaning project, deleting gradle caches.

Can supply stack trace / further info if requested.

```
    /home/nigel/flutter-projects/flutterfire/packages/firebase_auth/example/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:12: error: duplicate class: io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
public final class GeneratedPluginRegistrant {                          
             ^                                                          
1 error                                                                 
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.             
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: Did you run flutter clean?

Comment: yes. I run flutter clean

Comment: do you have the latest firebase auth plugin in pubspec.yaml ?

Comment: mmm.. yes It on my git

Comment: validate that all your packeges and plugins are up to date

Comment: I already updated

Comment: I get my previously version in git.And get build.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to  `/android/app/src/main/java`

if there are two folders

delete one of them and run your application

if the error comes again, then delete the other folder instead of the first one.

---

in your case navigate `/android/app/src/main/java/`
and delete **io** folder and run your application

It will work... (If God Will)